# Writing User linked data in firebase user database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this ReactJS app I created, I have Login, Register and Dashboard page ...

So the data structure of a USER in firebase is this

I here are my user auth function

```
import { ref, firebaseAuth } from './../Components/config'

 // export const ref = firebase.database().ref()
 // export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth

export function auth (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
    .then(saveUser)
}

export function logout () {
  return firebaseAuth().signOut()
}

export function login (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
}

export function resetPassword (email) {
  return firebaseAuth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
}

export function saveUser (user) {
  return ref.child(`users/${user.uid}/info`)
    .set({
      email: user.email,
      uid: user.uid,
      number:0
    })
    .then(() => user)
```

Respectively I call the separate function  from the separate components

(e.g. `login()` function from `<Login/>` component)

So I  wonder how can I  make, a function to do the following:

1 - Find the currently logged user

2- set a new value to the `number` property of his firebase account data.

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Damn ...  I  still can't figure out how to update the number property of the user

Comment: I answered your question on your duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487388/firebase-user-updateprofile-not-working-in-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I searched the documentation,  fond a `updateProfile()` function  but for some reason, it's not working

```
changeNumberToNew = () =>{
    var user = firebaseAuth().currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
          user.updateProfile({
            number: "777"
          }).then(() => {
            console.log("Number changer");
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        console.log("No user")
      }
  };
```