# Firebase user.updateProfile({...}) not working in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I have this ReactJS app, there is a user database,

The function for creating the user is this

```
import { ref, firebaseAuth } from './../Components/config'

export function auth (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
    .then(saveUser)
}
export function saveUser (user) {
  return ref.child(`users/${user.uid}/info`)
    .set({
      email: user.email,
      uid: user.uid,
      number: "" //custom
    })
    .then(() => user)
}
```

as you see the user is made of 3 properties, email, uid, and a custom number property which initially is "",

I have a

```
changeNumberToNew = (n) =>{
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
          user.updateProfile({
            number: n
          }).then(() => {
            console.log("Number changer");
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        console.log("No user")
      }
  };
```

and a button  to  call the function

```
<button onClick={this.changeNumberToNew(4)}>Click to change number</button>
```

When i  click the button the promise is resolver leading to the execution of

```
console.log("Number changer")
```

but when I go and look at the firebase database object .. nothing changes, even if a reload and wait still nothing changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase v3 updateProfile Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559457/firebase-v3-updateprofile-method)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you are confusing the user object in your database with the user in your authentication module. They are not the same.

You save a 'copy' of your user to the database when you say the following in the first chunk.

```
ref.child(`users/${user.uid}/info`)
    .set({
      email: user.email,
      uid: user.uid,
      number: ""
    })
```

Then in the second chunk of code you try and update the current user in your authentication module. Not good. You should be updating your database, not your authentication module.

```
var user = firebase.**auth()**.currentUser

if (user != null) {
  user.updateProfile({...})
}
```

I don't think you can create a custom field on the current User in the authentication module. The updateProfile() is used to update the fields you get by default from the provider, such as email, display name, photoURL etc. You can't create new ones.

You should update the copy of the user in your **database** and then reference that when you need the value of 'number'.

You change function should probably be more like...

```
changeNumberToNew = (n) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
     ref.child(`users/${user.uid}/info`).update({number: n})
     .then(() => console.log("Number changer"))
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } else {
      console.log("No user")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth `updateProfile` only supports `displayName` and `photoURL`. It does not support client custom attributes. For admin custom attributes, you would need to use the admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

You are probably better off in this case saving these arbitrary custom fields in the database only (provided they do not require admin privileges).